# What is the equivalent of NSUserDefaults on Windows Phone 8 (C#)

Tags: c#, ios, windows-phone-8

I want to save data (key,value pair) in device storage, and read them later (even if application exited and launched again).

In iOS I do this using NSUserDefaults.

---

I tried  IsolatedStorageSettings, like this: 
`IsolatedStorageSettings appSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
 appSettings.Add("myKey","myValue");`

But when I relaunch the app in emulator, and try to get 
`appSettings["myKey"]` value I get an exception: `System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah , i found it :))

I forgot to call save() method :) 
`appSettings.Save();`